# AngularJS - Updating the $scope after service runs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
joolaControllers.controller('dsCtrl', function ($scope, dsService) {
  dsService.getList(function (list) {
    $scope.list = list;
  });
  $scope.dsDelete = function (dsName) {
    dsService.delete(dsName);
  }
});
```

And the following service:

```
joolaServices.service('dsService', function (socket) {
  this.getList = function (callback) {
    joolaio.objects.datasources.list(function() {
      socket.on('datasources/list:done', function(list) {
        callback(list.datasources);
      })  
    });
  };
  this.delete = function (dsName) {
    joolaio.objects.datasources.delete({name:dsName}, function() {
      socket.on('datasources/delete:done', function(list) {
        joolaio.objects.datasources.list()
      })
    });
  };
});
```

I want the `$scope.list` to get updated everytime I run the `joolaio.objects.datasources.list()` but not sure what's the correct way to go about it from my understanding I shouldn't put the listener inside the controller, is that accurate?

Comment: Can't you just pass a callback to the delete function like you're doing with getList?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `$watch` to observe the object and then update any other if its change:

[$watch(watchExpression, listener, objectEquality)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

Something like this, but you need to put this `joolaio.objects.datasources.list()` inside the `$scope` someway:

```
scope.$watch('joolaio.objects.datasources.list()', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      $scope.list = joolaio.objects.datasources.list();
});
```